# How to mock global fetch in Jest

Tags: jestjs

```js
// io_mockglobal.test.js
import {expect, jest} from '@jest/globals';
import {logMovies} from './io';

global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ "id": 423638}),
  })
);
beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.mockClear();
});

test("mocks the global values",async()=>{ 
    const l= await logMovies()
    expect(l).toEqual({ "id": 423638});
 })`
```

```js
// io.js
import path  from 'path';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import fetch from 'node-fetch'


export async function logMovies() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs");
  const movies = await response.json();
  return movies[0]
}
```

Console:

```
● mocks the global values

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  -  0
    + Received  + 11
```

I am trying to mock the global fetch but it's returning the actual value from logMovies(). How can I mock the global fetch in Jest?

Comment: Can you share your whole code?

Comment: Actually that's the whole code beginner to the Jest trying to figure out global mocks skipped few import statements here we go added them.

Comment: Remove the import for fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock the global `fetch` but in your `logMovies` you use the imported `fetch`. Try removing the import, then it will use the global `fetch`